# Inconsistent Mouse Scrolls and Mouse Stops Clicking

Tags: windows-10, mouse, scrolling, logitech-mouse, mouse-click

I have a Logitech Performance MX wireless mouse.  Logitech's Set Point software will do some weird scrolling behavior.  Sometimes I will scroll 1 click of the wheel and it scrolls a few lines.  Other times, I will scroll 1 click of the wheel and it scrolls many lines.  It was very annoying.  So, I killed Set Point and the problem went away.  I then decided to uninstall Set Point.

Later, Set Point somehow reinstalled.  I uninstalled it and rebooted.  Now my mouse will work fine but then clicks stop working.  I can move the mouse but clicks do not register.  I can hit `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Delete` and then `Escape` and the mouse clicks work again.  I have to do this frequently.  I tried rebooting but the problem persists.

It is not the battery since the battery can be fully charged to almost empty and the behavior happens.

The solution can be an answer to either of these questions.  How do I resolve Set Point's problem of inconsistent scrolling?  How do I resolve the mouse clicks not registering?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a driver issue, perhaps you should check device manager and reinstall/update your drivers?

Comment: I uninstalled the driver and deleted it.  I rebooted and I still have the problem.

Comment: Ok, and by the way, did you use Settings to uninstall SetPoint? If it reinstalled, maybe you should try using appwiz.cpl

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to reinstall Windows 10.

This is a drastic solution and I would prefer something much less time consuming.

Comment: Why not try the fresh start option in windows 10? I don't know much about it, but it's like spring cleaning for windows but your apps/files are not uninstalled or removed. (Even if it says so, maybe backing up your data might be a good idea when using fresh start)

Comment: @AntPalmer The reinstall option pretty much did this.  It reinstalled the OS but left the documents alone.

Comment: @Nathan You can accept your own answer if you want to.

Comment: @AndrewMorton No thanks.  I would rather wait for and accept a better answer.

Comment: @Nathan Are you still stuck with the problem so that you could test a new answer? I'd suggest using something like [Revo Uninstaller](https://www.revouninstaller.com/) to see if that can find any remnants of SetPoint in the registry or elsewhere such that if it gets reinstalled it might not behave strangely any more.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I got a new laptop and the problem is no longer reproducible.  I did not get the new laptop to solve the problem... although that would be a more drastic answer than this answer.